# Rust Serde deserialization of a json response doesn't work for a particular field

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am trying to gather data from a json response in Rust, using serde, and I am running into a problem.

First, here is the relevant part of the json response

```
 {
    "data": {
         "id": "ws-eezeioA1J2dW3cwK",
         "relationships": {
                    "organization": {
                        "data": {
                            "id": "DevOps",
                            "type": "organizations"
                        }
                    },
                    "current-run": {
                        "data": {
                            "id": "run-XEFXdZj6MKwpoNJx",
                            "type": "runs"
                        },
                        "links": {
                            "related": "/api/v2/runs/run-XEFXdZj6MKwpoNJx"
                        }
                    },
            }
        }
}
```

and here are my structs in rust

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Workspace {
    data: WorkspaceData,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct WorkspaceData {
    id: String,
    relationships: WsRelashionships,
}
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct WsRelashionships {
    #[serde(alias = "current-run")]
    current_run: Data,
}
struct Data {
    id: String,
}
```

finally, the line of code that read the json reponse

```
workspace_data = serde_json::from_str(response.text().unwrap().as_str())?;
```

Basically, I want to extract the `"id"` field under  `data` and `"current-run"`, but I keep getting this error for the  `id` field under `"current-run"`

> Err(
> Serialization(
> Error("missing field `id`", line: 1, column: 1515),
> ), )

It's like it's not seeing the `"id"` field under current run.  Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, geez, I found it 5 mins after posting this.  I am missing one layer in my structs.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Workspace {
    data: WorkspaceData,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct WorkspaceData {
    id: String,
    relationships: WsRelashionships,
}
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct WsRelashionships {
    #[serde(alias = "current-run")]
    current_run: CurrentRunData,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct CurrentRunData {
    data: Data,
}

struct Data {
    id: String,
}
```